# Using auto to Return Different Lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, c++17, auto

So I'm curious if [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) gives me the flexibility to do this. I have [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096760/2642059) which contains the code:

```
template <typename T>
function<void(vector<pair<T, T>>&)> vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon) {
    if (0U == index){
        return [&](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){ output.push_back(polygon.back());
                                                output.push_back(polygon.front());
                                                output.push_back(polygon[1U]); };
    }else if (index == (polygon.size() - 1U)){
        return [&](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){ output.push_back(polygon[polygon.size() - 2U]);
                                                output.push_back(polygon.back());
                                                output.push_back(polygon.front()); };
    }else{
        return [&](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){ output.push_back(polygon[index - 1U]);
                                                output.push_back(polygon[index]);
                                                output.push_back(polygon[index + 1U]); };
    }
}
```

I think that I should be able to change the function signature to: `auto vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon)` thereby preserving closure type optimization. Additionally I'd really like to have my lambda parameter be `auto&` rather than `vector<pair<T, T>>&`.
Would [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support these changes?

Comment: The lambdas have different types, therefore `auto` will fail to deduce the return type. If `index` was `constexpr` you could use `if constexpr` and make that decision at compile time.

Comment: For `auto vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon)`, what do you want deduced for the `auto`? Each lambda has a different type and, given they capture, they don't have a common type either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support these changes?

No. What you're asking for is to have a function that returns different types depending on a **runtime condition**. The only way to do that is type erasure - whether of the `std::function` kind or the standard OOP inheritance kind.

If you could lift the conditions to constant expressions, then you could accomplish this with `if constexpr` (or simply tag dispatching). But given that the second case is `index == vector.size() - 1`, I'm guessing this isn't possible.

---

That said, do you actually need different functions? Why not (NB: capture `index` by copy to avoid dangling reference):

```
template <typename T>
auto vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon) {
    return [&polygon, index](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){ 
        size_t lo = index == 0 ? polygon.size() - 1 : index - 1;
        size_t hi = index == polygon.size() - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;

        for (size_t offset : {lo, index, hi}) {       
            output.push_back(polygon[offset]);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Possibly:
`size_t lo = (index + polygon.size() - 1) % polygon.size();` and `size_t hi = (index + 1) % polygon.size();`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's so much more direct this way.

Answer (score 1):

No, the return type of a function cannot vary based off of non-template value function arguments.

You could write a variant factory like this:

```
template<class F, class T, T t, T...ts>
auto variant_from(
  F&& f,
  std::integral_constant<T, t> which,
  std::integer_sequence<T, ts...>
) ->
std::variant< std::decay_t<
  std::result_of_t< F&&( std::integral_constant<T, t>)>
>... > {
  return std::forward<F>(f)( which );
}
```

using this we can return a variant over the lambdas, which is about as close as you can get.

```
template <typename T>
auto vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon) {
  auto choice_list = std::make_index_sequence<3>{};
  auto algorithm = [&polygon, index](auto choice) {
    if constexpr (choice==0){
      return [&polygon](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){ 
        output.push_back(polygon.back());
        output.push_back(polygon.front());    
        output.push_back(polygon[1U]);
      };
    }else if constexpr (choice == 1){
      return [&polygon](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){
        output.push_back(polygon[polygon.size() - 2U]);
        output.push_back(polygon.back());
        output.push_back(polygon.front());
      };
    }else{
      return [&polygon, index](vector<pair<T, T>>& output){
        output.push_back(polygon[index - 1U]);
        output.push_back(polygon[index]);
        output.push_back(polygon[index + 1U]); };
      }
    };
  if (index == 0)
    return variant_from( algorithm, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}, choice_list );
  else if (index == output.size()-1)
    return variant_from( algorithm, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>{}, choice_list );
  else
    return variant_from( algorithm, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>{}, choice_list );
}
```

I'm sure that can be cleaned up a bit.

`variant_from` uses the algorithm to deduce what the variant is a sum type over, then only stores one of them in the returned variant.  We call it in 3 different contexts that have the same return type, but a different value stored.

Note that `operator()` on `variant` doesn't do what we want, but we can augment it.