# How are Lambda Identifiers Captured?

Tags: c++, variables, lambda, reference, capture

I have posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096760/2642059), which contains the code:

```
template <typename T>
auto vertex_triangle(const size_t index, const vector<pair<T, T>>& polygon) {
    const auto& first = index == 0U ? polygon.back() : polygon[index - 1U];
    const auto& second = polygon[index];
    const auto& third = index == size(polygon) - 1U ? polygon.front() : polygon[index + 1U];

    return [&](auto& output){ output.push_back(first);
                              output.push_back(second);
                              output.push_back(third); };
}
```

I was thinking that `first`, `second`, and `third` could really be used as lambda identifiers like this:

```
[first = index == 0U ? polygon.back() : polygon[index - 1U],
 second = polygon[index],
 third = index == size(polygon) - 1U ? polygon.front() : polygon[index + 1U]](auto& output){ output.push_back(first);
                                                                                             output.push_back(second);
                                                                                             output.push_back(third); };
```

But I only want to capture by constant reference. Without specifying a type in the identifier how can I do this?

Comment: Each instance of a lambda is an an instance of a unique, nameless class. You cannot assign an "identifier" to a lambda, or any such thing.

Comment: @Sam.  I disagree, lambdas are first-class types.  And this has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: So you question is, to avoid capturing by value for constness, how to capture a const reference? BTW, that piece of code at the end is atrociously unreadable. I don't think it's worth it in this case.

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment to Rakete1111's excellent answer below, since all references stem from polygon, which is itself a const ref, std::vector::front(), and operator[] will return const references.

Comment: @StoryTeller That is pretty hard to read isn't it? I liked the idea of completely encapsulating variable lifespans within the lambda. Would there be a more readable way to accomplish that? I suppose we could use local statics in the body of the lambda huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't<sup>1</sup>. There is no place to put a cv-qualifier in a lambda capture list. You can have a look at the [relevant grammar](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture):

> ```
> init-capture:
>     identifier initializer
>     & identifier initializer
> ```

You also can't specify the type in a capture list (see grammar above).

What you can do however is capture by non-const reference by putting a `&` before the names:

```
[&first = index == 0U ? polygon.back() : polygon[index - 1U],
 &second = polygon[index],
 &third = index == size(polygon) - 1U ? polygon.front() : polygon[index + 1U]](auto& output){ output.push_back(first);
                                                                                             output.push_back(second);
                                                                                             output.push_back(third); };
```

Or just stick to your first snippet, which is way more readable too IMO.

---

<sup>1</sup> `polygon` is `const`, so in your case, `first`, `second` and `third` will actually be `const` if you capture them by reference in the capture list! But if it weren't, then no, for the reasons stated above.

Comment: The references will be const, since the vector reference polygon is itself const.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That is true, +1 for spotting this :P Thanks

Comment: And if `polygon` were not const, you could use [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) to make it so.

Comment: @Oktalist That is true too, but then you might just as well define the variables outside of the lambda :P